# Get IdentityUser by ID using MVC 5 Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

When creating another model `Testimonial` I store the active user's `Id` as the `Author` which is a string looking like: `00b9c6aa-010c-4cbd-ac16-c72d05e7906a`. In another view I want to display the name and other user information associated with that `Id` for each `Testimonial`. The view will contain information from many different users, not just the actively logged one. I cannot figure out how to get a user their information by `Id`.

How do I get the `IdentityUser` by `Id`?

All of the tables containing the users are default plus some additional columns. Within the table named `AspNetUsers`, I've got `Id`, `FirstName`, `Email`, etc. The `Id` is the key value and I would like to know how to (within the controller for `Testimonial`) retrieve the information for a given `Id`.

Comment: I assume that you have extended the default context that is generated by the MVC project template?  Have you created your new table - if so, please add to the question.

Comment: I have appended the question.

Comment: Yes, but you created a `Testimonial` table that contains the `Id` of the user that created it.  Was this done as a foreign key to the `ApplicationUser` table?

Comment: No. I am new to ASP.Net and SQL. If I changed it to be the foreign key, would there be an easy way to get each user's information?

Comment: Yes - you would be able to query the `Testimonial` table, and retrieve the associated user details in a single database operation.  How do you query your `Testimonial` table?  Is it via Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IdentityConfig.cs
   // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
        };
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) :
        base(userManager, authenticationManager) { }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

In your controller define the following properties

```
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set { _signInManager = value; }
    }
```

You can use the following method in the controller

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync("00b9c6aa-010c-4cbd-ac16-c72d05e7906a");
```

You can get the logged in user like the following

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(await SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync());
```

Comment: This only gets the logged in user.  I believe the poster wants to get the user details that relate to records in some other table.

Comment: var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync("00b9c6aa-010c-4cbd-ac16-c72d05e7906a"); works with any user Id while var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(await SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync()); used for the logged in user only.